# how to make web service changes backward compatible

Tags: java, android, web-services, compatibility

I'm new with web services an android development. I'm setting up a new Infrastructure with different services for my apps. When I deploy my web service to the server and put my android app in the store, maybe 1000 people install it on their phone.

Now, I do some changes in the web service and update some fields, values, etc. and I update the android app to the new web service version. Users become notify for an update, but maybe just 800/1000 user install this update. 
The problem is, 200 people, which didn't update their app can't use my new web service anymore becaus it response not the correct data.

How do I make changes to my web service, that both User Groups (the 800 new and the 200 not updated) can use a working app?

Comment: don't change you API ,but add new version which handles new user

Comment: but if I do that 5 times, I have 5 versions running parallel, isn't it?

Comment: yes always some users don't update your application ,if you change your API n times create n version if they can NOT be backward compatible